# Don't showing ClipDrawable in ImageView

Tags: android, kotlin, imageview, drawable

I have problem with ClipDrawable. I have this code:

```
private fun updateFirstImage(imageUri: String){
        Glide.with(requireContext()).asDrawable().load(imageUri).into(object: CustomTarget<Drawable>(){
            override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable, transition: Transition<in Drawable>?) {
                val clipDrawable = ClipDrawable(resource, Gravity.START, ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL)
                clipDrawable.level = 10000
                clipDrawable.invalidateSelf()
                binding.editorFirstImage.setImageDrawable(clipDrawable)
            }
            override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {}
        })
    }
```

But this drawable don't showing in imageview. I tried everythings. Do you have any ideas ?